# next config redirects regex match file extensions

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to write a redirect rule in next.config.js to redirect all requests with .pdf extension to an external destination. But I am getting the following error.

```
Error parsing `/:file(.(pdf)$)` https://err.sh/vercel/next.js/invalid-route-source
Reason: Capturing groups are not allowed at 8
```

is there any way to handle this in next.config.js?

```
async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:file(\.(pdf)$)',
        destination: 'https://some-other-website.com/:file',
        permanent: false
      }
    ];
}
```

Comment: Try using `/:file(.*\\.pdf$)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following works

```
async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:file(\.\+\.pdf)',
        destination: 'https://some-other-website.com/:file',
        permanent: false
      }
    ];
}
```